# Using PODS data with save_post

Tags: save-post, curl, pods-framework

I'm trying to use the save_post hook to send an SMS to a telephone number entered into a PODS custom post type. The SMS should be sent when the record is saved.

```
add_action( 'save_post_appointment', 'sendsms_save' );
function sendsms_save() {
    $username = 'username';
    $password = 'password';
    $msisdn = $_POST["mobile"];
    $content="Hi";
    $data =   "username=".$username."&password=".$password."&message=".urlencode($content)."&msisdn=".urlencode($msisdn);

    $ch = curl_init('http://bulksms.com/eapi/submission/send_sms/2/2.0');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    if ($response = curl_exec($ch)) 
    {
      echo "1";
    } 
    else 
    {
       echo "0";
    }

    curl_close ($ch);
}
```

Is the $_POST data available when you hook into save_post or will I have to select the latest record to get the telephone number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, whenever a post is saved you should see all of the input items in `$_POST` ... if you're not using something like xdebug to debug with, you could do something like:

```
echo "<pre>";
var_dump( $_POST );
echo "</pre>";
```

To test and see what is all included in $_POST ... note this is just for testing and is not recommended method of debugging, which I would strongly recommend using something like PHPStorm and xdebug ... and in that case all you would need to do is set a breakpoint in your code, and then just look at $_POST in the IDE to see what is available :P

https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/configuring-xdebug.html

```
add_action( 'save_post_appointment', 'sendsms_save' );
function sendsms_save() {
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump( $_POST );
    echo "</pre>";
}
```